# problems with uv4l-server URLs

Tags: raspberry-pi, webcam, uv4l

I have a uv4l server set up on my raspi which is serving a no-name webcam.  It is using the uvc driver.  The server built-in web page mostly works.  I can stream webrtc from the pi to my laptop browser, however the mjpeg button brings up a broken-image icon.

Most importantly, no urls seem to work directly from the server, such as http://raspberrypi:8080/stream/video.mjpeg.

Using the chrome inspection window on that url I can see a return of 200 but the server then closes the connection.  VLC is unable to open the connection either.

This is my uv4l command ...

```
/usr/bin/uv4l -k --sched-rr --mem-lock --config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf     \
             --driver uvc --driver-config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf       \
             --server-option=--editable-config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf  \
             --device-id=1908:2310
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that your UVC-based webcam does not support the `MJPEG` video format natively so you get a blank page from `UV4L`. As an alternative to the `uv4l-uvc` userspace driver, you can tell `UV4L` to make use of the `uvcvideo` kernel driver. For example, supposing `uvcvideo` creates `/dev/video0`, the commands would be something like:

```
modprobe uvcvideo
uv4l --external-driver --device-name=video0 --server-option '--port=9000'
```

However, if `uvcvideo` does not provide `MJPEG` either your problem would still remain.

Comment: The webcam definitely doesn't support mjpeg.  Just YUYV 640x480.  But then what is being sent out webrtc and where is it coming from?  I will try to analyse the webrtc stream and I will try your suggestion to try uvcvideo.

Comment: webrtc uses vp8 or h264, so there must be an transcoding from yuyv. However, in your question you are asking video.mjpeg, for which no yuyv->mjpeg transcoding exists

Comment: h264 would be fine, as long as there is no latency problem.  Combined with your suggestion for the external driver I may be in business.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled extensively and I think I understand what is going on even though I couldn't find any clear explanations.  The raspicam driver has a lot of features/options including encoding.  The uvc driver does nothing except pass the webcam stream through.  The uv4l server does no encoding either.

My webcam has only raw yuyv so I needed a real encoding solution.  I've used ffmpeg a lot so I chose it. It can encode using the broadcom h.264 hardware so it is only using 20% of the cpu.

I'm using the ffserver program instead of the uv4l server since I'm only serving http and it is a good match for ffmpeg.